# How to get Count group by specific field in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get distinct data as well as count data based on this distinct data. For example, I want to get distinct data for country and city while emp_id is different so based on distinct data we know how many emp_id fall in with country1 and city1 so in the output it will return as 2

```
Sample Data:
[
   {
      "emp_id":1,
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "emp_id":2,
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "emp_id":3,
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city2"
   }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
   {
      "count":2,
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city1"
   },
   {
      "count":1,
      "emp_country":"country1",
      "emp_city":"city2"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'emp_country': '$emp_country', 
        'emp_city': '$emp_city'
      }, 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'emp_county': '$_id.emp_country', 
      'emp_city': '$_id.emp_city', 
      'count': 1, 
      '_id': 0
    }
  }
])
```